# ListView Item problem

Tags: android, listview

i have a problem with my custom ListView. The items in the list dont fit with the width of the list and i dont know why.

Maybe the picture helps you.

[image]

ListView:

```
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:background="#626262">
        <AutoCompleteTextView android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="2" android:layout_height="45dip" android:layout_marginTop="2dip"></AutoCompleteTextView>
        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1" android:src="@drawable/lupe" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></ImageView>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/android:list" 
            android:background="#000000" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:cacheColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
  <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/image"
      android:layout_width="50dip"
      android:layout_height="50dip" 
      android:src="@drawable/icon" 
      android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/Buddystoptext"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical" 
      android:textSize="20dip" 
      android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" 
      android:text="Text" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

OnClick xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<!-- Non focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="false"
android:state_selected="false"
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/msg_bg_deselect" />
<item android:state_focused="false"
android:state_selected="true"
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/msg_bg_focus" />
<!-- Focused states -->
<item android:state_focused="true"
android:state_selected="false"
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/msg_bg_deselect" />
<item android:state_focused="true"
android:state_selected="true"
android:state_pressed="false"
android:drawable="@drawable/msg_bg_focus" />
<!-- Pressed -->
<item android:state_pressed="true"
android:drawable="@drawable/msg_bg_focus" />
</selector>
```

Can anybody help ?

Thank you.

Comment: Show us your code or XML-Layout definition.

Comment: later, im too silly to post code here o.O

Answer (score 1):

Your item's layout should have layout_width set to fill_parent instead of wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Gregory is right. Fill parent. But if that is an image your gonna have to do some [9-patch](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html) work as well. Depending on how your images are setup for scale.